# Should I reinstall nodemcu firmware if I uploaded a arduino sketch?

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

I have a nodemcu v3 and I'm trying some basic stuff

I installed the esp8266 board in Arduino IDE and then I uploaded a blink example.

But now I'm trying to upload Lua code using ESPLorer but I doesn't work properly. I press in open and set the baud rate to 115200 but I just get some infinite Chinese letters.

Should I reinstall the firmare or something?

Comment: What is the flash size you specified while uploading the code the first time? The flash size is set via the tools menu, and defaults to 512k in most esp8266 board selections. IF you had used 512k, you nodemcu bootloader is corrupted. Use 4M (3M) next time.

Comment: If you had used 512k you will have to re-program the bootloader. Idk what the process is for that.

Comment: It says 4M (1M SPIFFS)

Comment: Switch to 4M (3M SPIFFS) and try.

Comment: I used a utility five minutes ago called nodemcu flasher and I flashed. I think now I should Install the firmware right? and is okay that one Integer from 2015? https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/releases?after=1.4.0-master_20151229

Comment: Seems to work fine now, using the Integer Firmware 2015 and setting bard rate to 9600 thanks :D

Comment: Anything else you need or can this be "closed" i.e. accepted so that it doesn't show up as unanswered anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43509569/131929 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47510019/131929.

> Should I reinstall the firmare or something?

First you should make up your mind whether you want to conveniently program in Lua or whether you want to stick with Arduino (running on the NodeMCU-clone board). It is an either-or question. Flashing on of them to the module will erase the respective other.

And no, in case you want to use the NodeMCU firmware, you should not use those outdates binaries from 2015. Build a recent version conveniently in the cloud: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/build/.

P.S. if you're interested why I call yours a clone board you may want to read https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/ from yours truly.

Answer (score 0):

You must erase the flash of your NodeMCU before a new upload. If you ignore that, your software don't run appropriately. To do that, I'm using esptool:

```
python esptool.py --port COM9: erase_flash
```

In that example COM9: is the name of my USB/serial interface.

After that you can flash for example your ESP8266 with that line of code to add a boot part:

```
python esptool.py --port COM9: write_flash -fm dout 0x00000 boot_v1.5.bin
```

Use the preview line of code and adapt it to upload other parts of the map of the flash memory.